# Copying and pasting slides in LibreOffice Impress becomes exponentially slower with `libreoffice-gtk` installed

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, and while I'm mostly quite happy with it, I'm quite frustrated by the slowdowns I'm seeing in LibreOffice 5. In particular, with the default `libreoffice-gtk` package installed, every time I copy and paste a slide (which I do a lot to build custom animations for courses I'm teaching) it hangs the program for what appears to be a period of time that doubles with each copy. By the third or fourth copy the entire program hangs to the point where the window darkens for an appreciable period of time. The waiting time doesn't reset if I select a different slide to copy and paste. This has gotten to the point where it's completely infeasible to copy slides, which is so critical to my normal workflow that it's unacceptable for what I'm trying to do.

I can prevent this by uninstalling `libreoffice-gtk`, but that makes the editor interface significantly harder to use (the icons are tiny and the file menus no longer have my preferences or even a "recently changed" setting).

I've read around online and it seems like there's a known issue with LibreOffice 5 being excessively slow on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not sure what's causing it, and if there's anything I can do to fix it I'm game to try it out.

Any suggestions on how to speed things up, or any alternate options I could try that doesn't make me compromise between a nice interface and fast editing?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your version of LibreOffice but see https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101213 about performance regressions. It's mainly about Calc though.